# Page not found 404 on Django site

Tags: python, django

I've started with the online tutorial on Django(1.9) from thenewboston channel on YouTube which is building a simple music app. 
However I am getting the following error:

```
Page not found (404)
Request Method:     GET
Request URL:    http://127.0.0.1:8000/music
Using the URLconf defined in website.urls, Django tried these URL patterns, in this order:
^admin/
The current URL, music, didn't match any of these.
```

Here are my files:

website/website/settings.py

```
...
INSTALLED_APPS = [
    'music',
    'django.contrib.admin',
    'django.contrib.auth',
    'django.contrib.contenttypes',
    'django.contrib.sessions',
    'django.contrib.messages',
    'django.contrib.staticfiles',
]

...
ROOT_URLCONF = 'website.urls'
...
```

website/website/urls.py

```
from django.conf.urls import include, url
from django.contrib import admin


urlpatterns = [
    url(r'^music/', include('music.urls')),
    url(r'^admin/', admin.site.urls),
]
```

website/music/urls.py

```
from django.conf.urls import url
from . import views

urlpatterns = [
    url(r'^$', views.index, name='index'),
]
```

website/music/views.py

```
from django.http import HttpResponse


def index(request):
    return HttpResponse("<h1>This is the Music app homepage</h1>")
```

P.S: I've made sure that I am editing the correct urls.py file and it is placed in the correct directory also I guess, unlike the other similar questions asked about this problem

EDIT: I renamed my root directory from "website" to "website1" just to resolve the ambiguity related to reference of "website" and music and admin sections are working fine now but the django server homepage(http://127.0.0.1:8000/) is displaying the following error now:

```
Page not found (404)
Request Method:     GET
Request URL:    http://localhost:8000/

Using the URLconf defined in website.urls, Django tried these URL patterns, in this order:

    ^music/
    ^admin/

The current URL, , didn't match any of these.
```

EDIT 2: Issue fixed, renamed the root directory from "website" to "website1". Seems Django was confused by multiple directories named "website"

Comment: Have you tried moving `music` in the end of `INSTALLED_APPS` and also moving the `^music/` url pattern after the `^admin/` one?

Comment: tried both.. didn't work :(

Comment: Try to put `music.apps.MusicConfig` instead of `music` in your `INSTALLED_APPS`. 

You can try to reinstall django.

Comment: To resolve your last error, I think you should remove 'music' from the url(r'^music/', include('music.urls')). It should be url(r'', include('music.urls')).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Everything you did is correct. Make sure your files are saved and restart the server. If it's still not working, you can instead import the music urls like so:

```
from music import urls as music_urls
```

And then change the music url line to this:

```
url(r'^music/', include(music_urls)),
```

Comment: It's not even trying your url against music/ so I would verify that you're editing the correct url file, and make sure it's saved. If it's not that, you must be doing something else wrong outside of django

Answer (score 0):

Only a partial answer: The error message lists all the urls that are known. In your case, only

```
^admin/
```

is known (according to the error message you posted), it does not know about `^music/`. I don't see why it does not know about `^music/`, though.

Edit: Although the include(string) should work, you could try to replace it with include(music.urls) and add an import statement on music.urls.

Comment: Yes! i noticed the same. Also the admin page is running fine

Comment: Added a suggestion concerning the include statement.

Comment: Tried that before asking this question. But that too didn't work :(

Comment: Then its quite mysterious. As the files you posted look correct, I would check whether this is their real content (e.g., using `cat`). Maybe your editor is playing a trick on you?